# Calculate brighness, contrast, hue and saturation level in an image using java

Tags: java, image, brightness, hue, contrast

How can we calculate the brightness, contract, hue and saturation numbers in an image using java programming. Any formula, code snippet appreciated.

Comment: I don't think such formula exists. If some research exists you should look for some scientific papers. Certainly you shouldn't ask here some specific java code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use HSV model to calculate the values, where H is Hue, S is saturation and V is value( or brightness)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here RGB are the Red, Green and Blue value of pixel which I am assuming you are able to read with help of some image processing library.

Comment: you can use java.awt.Color to get the HSB values of any RGB values.

Comment: Hi, I am interested in calculating the saturation. What is `max` and `min` there?

Comment: @Solace (late but), `max` is literally the maximum value and `min` is the minimum. The RGB values are specified in decimal, so if you have `rgb(0,102,51)` (sort of dark green-ish) then the `max` would be `102` and `min` would be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be difficult to implement using only native Java libraries, however you might be interested in some 3rd party library like for example [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/features.html) which enables you to control contrast, brigthness and so on. There are also a couple of [examples on the aformentioned page](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/examples/).